# How to find this limit of Bessel function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, functions, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have a question about limit of Bessel function.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x \bigg [ (J_p (x) )^2 + (Y_p (x) )^2 \bigg ]
$$

Where, $ J_p (x)$ is Bessel function of first kind $ Y_p (x)$ is general solution of Bessel function.

I start like this from the definition and results of Bessel function of the first kind. Below first two are standard results for Bessel function for large $x$.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} J_p (x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{x\pi }} cos( x - \frac{pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) 
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} Y_p (x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{x\pi }} sin( x - \frac{pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) 
$$

$$
\implies  \lim_{x \to \infty} \bigg [ x \frac{2}{x\pi}cos^2( x - \frac{pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) +  x \frac{2}{x\pi}sin^2( x - \frac{pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) \bigg ]
$$

$$
\implies  \lim_{x \to \infty} \bigg [ \frac{2}{\pi}cos^2( x - \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) +  \frac{2}{\pi}sin^2( x - \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac {p\pi}{2}) \bigg ]
$$

Now, $sin(x),cos(x)$ are bounded between $[-1,1]$ So, what this limit becomes?

*edit* 
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Seems correct?

Comment: Why didn't you square the sine and cosine?

Comment: @GEdgar It was typo, sorry. Now corrected.

Comment: Now perhaps you know an identity about $\cos^2+\sin^2$

Comment: @GEdgar you are correct. I used that. Does the answer seem right?